# MOSS 2007 Unable to Connect to Database after Config Database Move

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2007, move

I am in the process of moving all our SharePoint DB's from a SQL 2005 server to a new 2008 server, and after moving the config database, everything seems ok, except when I click on "Timer Job Status" (under Central Admin > Operations > Global Configuration) I receive a "Unable to connect to database.  Check database connection information and make sure the database server is running." error.

I get the following entries in the log regarding this:

> 12/03/2010
> 13:51:41.80
> w3wp.exe
> (0x09E0)
> 0x09AC
> Windows SharePoint Services
> General
> 8e2r
> Medium
> Possible mismatch
> between the reported error with code =
> 0x8107053b and message: "Unable to
> connect to database.  Check database
> connection information and make sure
> the database server is running." and
> the returned error with code
> 0x81020024.
>
> 12/03/2010
> 13:51:45.61
> OWSTIMER.EXE
> (0x0744)
> 0x0DD8
> Windows SharePoint Services
> Database
> 6f8e
> Critical
> SQL Database
> 'SP_Test_Config' on SQL Server
> instance 'test-server' not found.
> Additional error information from SQL
> Server is included below.  Cannot open
> database "SP_Test_Config" requested by
> the login. The login failed.

It should be noted that in order to ensure that it was no longer using the config database on the old server, I detached the original SP_Test_Config database in SQL Management Studio.

Obviously there are still references to the old SP_Test_Config database on the old 2005 server. How do I remove these references? Or, barring that, how do I move the config database in such a way that no references to the old 2005 server will remain?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you are going to move database from SQl Server 2005 32bit to Sql Server 2008 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but what we ended up doing (basically start from scratch using SQL Aliases):

First, create the SQL Server alias. This will make it so if you need to move the databases again in the future, you can just migrate all the databases to the new SQL Server, and change your SQL Server alias to point at that server. This should save you a lot of trouble and heartache in the future.

1. Run SQL Server Client Configuration Utility at: C:\Windows\System 32\cliconfig.exe.
2. Under the Alias tab, create a SQL Server Alias for the new SQL Server.

Now, recreate the farm.

1. Run stsadm -o preparetomove on all content DB's Backup all content DB's and copy to new SQL server
2. Remove all servers from farm using SharePoint Configuration Wizard
3. Recreate farm using SharePoint Configuration Wizard with the alias of the SQL Server you created above
4. Recreate all web apps with temp content DB's
5. Run stsadm -o deletecontentdb on all temp content databases created in step 4
6. Run stsadm -o addcontentdb using copied production databases as content database
7. Troubleshoot ad nauseum